# openalpr error -bash: alpr: command not found

Tags: opencv

When I type `alpr --help` and entered, then it showed   `-bash: alpr: command not found error message`. How to solve this problem? I followed this method to install all the stuff https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(Ubuntu-Linux)

Comment: The page you linked to is for ubuntu are you running ubuntu? Which of three methods did you use? After installing did you run the tests?

Comment: I use in raspberry pi. No I didn't run tests.

Comment: I know you are using a Raspberry Pi, but what operating system, are you using? Raspbian? You only answered some of my questions without the info we can't begin to help you.

Comment: Yep. Raspbian in raspberry pi.

Comment: And again which of the 3 methods listed on the linjed page did you use?